# HTTPS mocking with nock and mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, stripe-payments, nock

I am trying to mock a request to stripe, but I am having a hard time. I am doing something simple at the top of my mocha `describe` block that looks like

```
describe('Billing call', function(){
  var api = Nock('https://api.stripe.com').log(console.log);
  // ... down here there's a call that uses a stripe api
});
```

Just to see if it intercepts anything at all. But it doesn't. I can't find any examples of this anywhere, and I'm afraid that Nock doesnt support it, in which case I need to find a better tool.

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Nock certainly supports HTTPS calls, from their [documentation](https://github.com/pgte/nock#support-for-http-and-https):

> By default nock assumes HTTP. If you need to use HTTPS you can specify the https:// prefix like this:

```
var scope = nock('https://secure.my.server.com')
   // ...
```

Your nock code looks off. First off, since you said you can't find any examples anywhere I'll suggest you check out [this](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/nodejs-testing-strategies) testing video on PluralSight, the 4th module literally goes through the process of interfacing with Stripe in particular.

To stub customer creation in Stripe, you would do this:

```
var stripeNock = nock("https://api.stripe.com/v1")
                .post("/customers")
                .reply(200, {
                     //Mock Stripe Response
                }
```

Just inserting that bit of code should cause all other calls to Stripe return a 404. If you insert that and get a 404 anywhere else (or your mocked Stripe response for a customer creation), you'll know Nock is working.